# Scalaz functional composition with future

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have 2 data structures itemDto and itemEntity and they look like this.

```
trait ItemDto{
  def id: Long
  def name: String
}

trait ItemEntity {
  def id: Long
  def name: String
}

case class Entity(id: Long, name: String) extends ItemEntity

case class Dto(id: Long, name: String) extends ItemDto
```

I'd like to set up a pipe line that looks like this

```
ItemDto => ItemEntity => ItemEntity => Future[ItemEntity] => Future[ItemEntity] => Future[ItemDto]
```

I have some mapper functions as well

```
object ItemMapper {

  def mapDtoToEntity(dto: ItemDto): ItemEntity = {
    Entity(dto.id, dto.name)
  }

  def mapEntityToDto(entity: ItemEntity): ItemDto = {
    Dto(entity.id, entity.name)
  }
}
```

a function that increments the entity's id

```
object ItemEntity{
  def incrementId(entity: ItemEntity) = Entity(entity.id + 1, entity.name)
}
```

and there is a repository to save the entity

```
object ItemRepository {

    def save(entity: ItemEntity): Future[ItemEntity] = {
        Future{entity}
    }
}
```

finally my method that combines all these functions to do something looks like this

```
import ItemMapper._
import ItemRepository.save
import ItemEntity.incrementId

def addItem(dto: ItemDto) = {
    (mapDtoToEntity _ >>> incrementId >>> save >>> {_ map (incrementId _ >>> mapEntityToDto) })(dto)
}
```

After the save method is called in the chain, I have to break into another function.  My question, is there a way to lift the value out of the future and put it back in so that my pipeline looks something like this?

```
(mapDtoToEntity _ >>> incrementId >>> save ?!? incrementId ?!? mapEntityToDto)(dto)
```

Where `?!?` is the hypothetical operator.

It could be from the scala library as well.  It doesn't need to be from scalaz.

Answer (score 1):

The most useful concept from scalaz (or cats) to compose functions which return some `F[_]` (like `Future` here) is the `Keisli` arrow.

`Kleisli` makes it easy to compose multiple `A => F[B]` functions. Here we actually only have one `ItemEntity => Future[ItemEntity]` function.

We can create a `Kleisli[Future, ItemDto, ItemEntity]` from the first 3 functions and then map over it using the two last :

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val composition1: Kleisli[Future, ItemDto, ItemDto] =
  Kleisli(mapDtoToEntity _ >>> incrementId >>> save)
    .map(incrementId _ >>> mapEntityToDto)
```

The actual operation you want to do is `save`, the rest is a transformation from `Dto` to `Entity` and back while incrementing the id (twice).

We can do the transformation and the incrementation before and after `save` by calling `dimap` (an operation we get from `Profunctor`) on `Kleisli(save)` :

```
val composition2: Kleisli[Future, ItemDto, ItemDto] =
  Kleisli(save).dimap(
    mapDtoToEntity _ >>> incrementId,
    incrementId _ >>> mapEntityToDto)
```

Or by using `dimap` twice :

```
val composition3: Kleisli[Future, ItemDto, ItemDto] =
  Kleisli(save).dimap(incrementId, incrementId)
               .dimap(mapDtoToEntity, mapEntityToDto)
```

Which all give the same result :

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val futureDto: Future[ItemDto] = composition3(Dto(1L, "test"))
Await.result(futureDto, 1.second)
// ItemDto = Dto(3,test)
```

---

With cats this would look more or less the same :

- cats doesn't (currently) have the `>>>` operator, so it would need to be replaced by `andThen`.
- `dimap` is curried, so we would write `dimap(f)(g)` instead of `dimap(f, g)`.

Comment: Thanks for the really good explanation of the kleisli.  I was somewhat familiar with it before and now have a better grasp on it.  I was really wondering if there was an operator that did this automatically and it doesn't look like there is. btw, the double increment was a contrived example of multiple operations in the pipeline.  I'm not doing that in my projects.